# How is it possible that doubling a force on a fixed mass causes its acceleration to triple?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

[image]

So the suggested solution is A. But here's what I don't get, when the F is doubled, how is it possible that the acceleration(A) tripled?

If the answer is m.a should the question be "a person needs to push the car by a force of 4F to give the car an acceleration of 3a?

Comment: Why would it not be possible? You might have expected that doubling the force would cause a doubled acceleration - which would also be true, if that force was the **only** force. But it is *not* the only force. Acceleration does not depend on just the force you apply; it depends on the **total** force.

Comment: How can a resistive force makes you accelerate faster?

Comment: F is not the sum of forces. It is NOT ma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton 2nd law says that **total force** (or **the sum of all forces**) causes acceleration:

$$\sum F=ma$$

Imagine having a resistive force of $1 \;\mathrm N$ while applying $2\;\mathrm N$. The total force is

$$\sum F=\underbrace{2\;\mathrm N}_{applied}-\underbrace{1\;\mathrm N}_{resistive}=1 \;\mathrm N$$

Now double your applied force. The total force becomes:

$$\sum F=\underbrace{4\;\mathrm N}_{applied}-\underbrace{1\;\mathrm N}_{resistive}=3 \;\mathrm N$$

Total force $\sum F$ is now tripled, so the acceleration $a$ is tripled (they are proportional according to Newton's 2nd law). The applied force caused this. It can triple the acceleration by doubling itself because the resistive force sort of "offsets" the acceleration value.

Similarly, as an example, if a friend applies, say, $100\;\mathrm N$ to push furniture up the stairs, and I aid by pushing with only $1\;\mathrm N$, then clearly, even if I double my effort to $2\;\mathrm N$, we will not also double the acceleration.

We clearly cannot relate the proportional force change directly to the acceleration change **when other forces are involved**.

Because, **a force** does not cause acceleration. That is a misunderstanding. Only **the *total* force** causes acceleration. Newton's 2nd law does **not** say $$\require{cancel}\cancel{F=ma}\quad \text{but rather} \quad\sum F=ma$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a constant resistive force so you could just solve the simultaneous equation $F - R = ma$ and $2F - R = 3ma$ to get R, which is the resistive force.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer:
One needs to take the resistive force into account. Normally we just use Newton's 2nd law as $F=ma$ and assume no resistance in the equation. Here we need to consider resistance so we call the resistive force $R$ and modify the equation to: $$F-R=ma$$ This is our base condition.

Pushing the car with force $2F$ to give an acceleration of $3a$ means that we express this condition as $$2F-R=3ma$$ since the resistive force is unaffected.

As the resistive force is constant we can rearrange the expressions to $F-ma=R$ and $2F-3ma=R$, and then equate them as $$F-ma=2F-3ma$$
$$=> 2F-F=3ma-ma$$
$$=> F=2ma$$

Taking our original equation $F-R=ma$, and substituting $F=2ma$ yields $$2ma-R=ma$$
$$=>R=2ma-ma$$
$$R=ma$$

which is the answer (a) which was given as the solution. So no, the question should not have a force of $4F$. You can take the same approach using a force of $4F$ to see what the acceleration would be in that case.

Comment: In a mathematical view this is true, but if the resistive force is m.a, which is equivalent to F, then the person with 2F would need to move against this resistive force (F) and the effective force would be +F, and the car accelerates at 3a, which basically contradicts the first statement which is F accelerates the car by 'a'. I'm assuming this resistive force is friction, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @KEVINIOP F is NOT equal to ma in this problem. F is only one of the forces acting on the car. The correct working relation for forces and accelerations is $a=\sum F_j / m$.  You must take a vector sum of ALL the forces. F is only one of the $F_j$. Look at the math in the answer.